# focus parent view swtbot

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, swtbot

Using bot.viewByTitle() is not finding the view in which the present view is contained.I mean after selecting project name in project explorer in eclipse ,I am unable to select project explorer view again.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a views own bot (by calling `bot()` on a `SWTBotView`) you cannot find any elements that are not part of that view.

You should use the Workbench Bot instead.

```
SWTWorkbenchBot bot = new SWTWorkbenchBot();
bot.viewByTitle("My View");
```